# Adapt a CIE-XYZ color from an Observer/Illuminant to another one

Tags: algorithm, colors, photo, color-space

How do I adapt a color defined in `CIE 1931 XYZ` color space with a specific Observer and Illuminant to another observer and illuminant?

Say I have a color `c` that is defined using `D65 Illuminant` and `2° observer`, where

```
c = (x: 44.6609, y: 76.106, z: 12.3365)
```

How do I convert `c` to, say, `Illuminant D50` with `10° observer`?

The white point for D65 Illuminant with 2° observer is:

```
95.047, 100, 108.883
```

The white point for D50 Illuminant with 10° observer is:

```
96.720, 100, 81.427
```

This question is similar to [Converting spectral data for given Observer/Illuminant to another Observer/Illuminant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16340265/converting-spectral-data-for-given-observer-illuminant-to-another-observer-illum), but I'm specifically interested in the math behind the adaptation.

What I'm looking for is the set of equations (or matrices if any) that allow me to adapt a color, from an illuminant/observer to another illuminant/observer.

An algorithm / implementation is also acceptable if it demonstrates the math behind it.

Answer (score 2):

There is no such a thing as a standard conversion from an observer to another.

It is possible to come up with a transformation that maps an observer to another but it is no trivial and only make sense between observers of same degree, e.g. CIE 1931 2 Degree Standard Observer to CIE 2015 2 Degree Standard Observer.

Another alternative is to spectrally recover (or upsample) your colour sample to produce a metamer and re-integrate it to CIE XYZ tristimulus values under the new observer. This will introduce errors that are impossible to quantify as you do not have the original spectral reflectance of your colour sample.

If you think about all the RGB colourspaces, e.g. sRGB, DCI-P3, that are not spectrally defined, you can imagine that this is a huge issue.

It is however possible to convert between different illuminants under the same observer.

Comment: Please see: you can convert between different illuminants/observers: nixsensor.com/free-color-converter However, no algorithm is given.

Comment: You cannot convert between observers, there is no standard for that.

Answer (score -1):

Considering the conversion from https://www.nixsensor.com/free-color-converter/, I got the same values using the approach reported at http://www.brucelindbloom.com/ "Math" > "Chromatic adaptation". I recommend reading chapter 6 "Chromatic-Adaptation Transforms and Colour Appearance" of book "Computational Colour Science Using MATLAB".
An example of converting from xyz_C/10° = [0.4018 0.4807 0.1175] to  xyz_D65/2° = [0.3956 0.4824 0.1113]:

Matlab/Octave code:

```
clear all
    
% initial xyz
xyz = [0.4018 0.4807 0.1175];
    
%reference illuminant tristimulus
%from
ils=[0.97286 1 1.1614]; %C/10°
%to
ild=[0.95047 1 1.08883]; %D65/2°

%Bradford adaptation matrix
MA=[0.8951000  0.2664000 -0.1614000
-0.7502000  1.7135000  0.0367000
 0.0389000 -0.0685000  1.0296000];

s=MA*ils'; %Bruce Justin Lindbloom Eq 3
d=MA*ild'; %Bruce Justin Lindbloom Eq 4

M=inv(MA)*[diag(d./s)]*MA; %Bruce Justin Lindbloom Eq 2

% converted xyz
nxyz=[M*xyz']'
```

There are Matlab/Octave and Python source code here: http://scottburns.us/matlab-octave-and-python-source-code-for-refl-recon-chrom-adapt/

Comment: Two standard observers are like two different persons, it is not possible to convert from one person vision to another without some sort of mapping between the two in the form of a 3x3 matrix, a polynomial transform or a LUT. There is no standard on how to do that and you have no such mapping in your maths thus what you are doing is incorrect.

Comment: Thank you for your comments Kel Solaar. Can we conclude that the conversions of <https://www.nixsensor.com/free-color-converter/> are incorrect?

Comment: Indeed, it is incorrect!