# Is there a way to convert between D65/2 to C/2 observer/illuminant?

Tags: algorithm, color-space, systemcolors, color-conversion

I am attempting to recreate color conversion that we can find from https://www.easyrgb.com on an excel using VBA to set up the calculation. My aim is converting from HunterLAB (C/2) to XYZ (C/2) to sRGB (C/2). However, there's a discrepancy going from XYZ to sRGB because of the default observer/illumant used in the formula is D65/2 like shown [XYZ to sRGB formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K4dKH.png). This is somewhat similar to this question: [Adapt a CIE-XYZ color from an Observer/Illuminant to another one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76196116/adapt-a-cie-xyz-color-from-an-observer-illuminant-to-another-one)
The responses from this question stated that it is not possible to convert between different observers. However, what if the observer is the same, is there a way to convert between the different illuminants?

I am looking for the math behind this conversion if such things exist. The image here showed that it is possble to convert from one illuminant to another [online conversion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ct57T.png).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to convert between illuminants under a given observer, this is the process known as [chromatic adaptation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chromatic_adaptation). There are many algorithms available for that. One of the most common ones is the **Von Kries** chromatic adaptation. Bruce Lindbloom has the maths for it [here](http://www.brucelindbloom.com).

We have a reference Python implementations for VonKries and more in [Colour](https://github.com/colour-science/colour/tree/develop/colour/adaptation):

- CIE 1994
- CMCCAT2000
- Fairchild (1990)
- Von Kries
- Zhai et al. (2018)

Comment: Thank you for your input. I would like to ask where can i find the Python implementations reference that you mentioned? Is that something I would need to purchase? I am using the matrix i found on the Lindbloom website but it seems like it's not converting to the correct values for me.

Comment: It is open source, free and licensed under the BSD-3 terms here: https://github.com/colour-science/colour/blob/develop/colour/adaptation/vonkries.py

Comment: The main point of my calculation is to go from Hunter LAB to XYZ to RGB all using C/2, I have the formula for converting Hunter LAB to XYZ, but from XYZ to RGB the matrix i used is giving me correct results. For example, when I entered L =0, 50, 100, with a & b =0, i would get 255 for RGB. However,  when I attempted different values, i do not get matching RGB with what online calculator gave me. I think it comes down to the matrix being wrong. Is it possible if you could explain to me which matrix to use for the chromatic adaption without using Python implementations?

Comment: Assuming you are choosing the Von Kries method, you could use the Bradford or CAT16 chromatic adaptation transform (CAT) as input along with the source and target whitepoint. The CAT matrices can be sourced here: https://github.com/colour-science/colour/blob/develop/colour/adaptation/datasets/cat.py

Comment: I tried using the matrices provided in your link but still could not obtain the correct values when converting to RGB. The formula I used is obtain from matheasyrgb, but their formula is based on D65/2, is there a separate formula for C/2 or is it the same formula but with different white point?

Comment: I get reasonably close to the EasyRGB result: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1QiHZWOesoOIOYbYfjOgvjYrUZ_4GSNXB